# DB2 -- How to use LTRIM scalar function with 2 arguments?

Tags: database, db2

I am new to DB2 (using version 10.1) and I'm trying to execute a simple `ltrim` function in a test query.

```
select ltrim(',1,2,3,4', ',') from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

This results in the following error:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=LTRIM;FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.65.77
```

Based on the documentation [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0002412.html), it seems my example should work. Note, I can use the alternative `trim` function *or* the 1-arg version of `ltrim`:

```
select trim(l ',' from ',1,2,3,4') from sysibm.sysdummy1;
select ltrim(' test') from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

And those works fine!

Are there some fundamental differences between the 2-arg form of `ltrim` and the other examples I provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function was [added in DB2 10.1 fix pack 2](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0060633.html) -- you may want to upgrade.

Comment: Yes I was down a fixpack. Strange I wouldn't normally associate a "fixpack" as something that adds new features and changes API's, but OK...

Answer (score 1):

Making some guesses here, but are you sure you're on `10.1`? That version of that function you're trying to use appears to have been added in 10, so if you're on `9.x`, it won't work.

If you are, you might check and see if your schema path includes `SYSIBM`:

```
SELECT CURRENT_PATH FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

The "old" one-argument version of the function is in `SYSFUN`, which (if your path doesn't include `SYSIBM`) might be why you're still able to use that version.

If `SYSIBM` isn't in your path, you can try changing it using:

```
SET PATH = SYSIBM, CURRENT_PATH
```

Comment: +1 for the idea about `PATH`, but it seems to be correct: `"SYSIBM","SYSFUN","SYSPROC","SYSIBMADM","DB2INSTF"`

Answer (score 0):

Why not try [STRIP()](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0023197.html) instead:

```
VALUES STRIP(',1,2,3,4', L, ',');
```

(side note: It is simpler to use the VALUES statement, rather than SELECT FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)